# In Angular, can I pass a constant to a constant?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, constants

Can I define a constant in angular, which itself depends on a constant being passed to it? [Here's a contrived example](http://jsbin.com/yizidikucu/1/edit?html,js,output):

```
angular
  .constant("names", ["Bob", "Jane"])
  .constant("friends", ["names", getFriends]);

function getFriends(names) {
  var friends = {};

  names.forEach(function(name) {
    friends[name] = { firstName: name };
  });

  return friends;
}
```

So essentially, the `names` constant defines an array of names, which I then pass to a function to generate a bunch of object literals.

This code definitely doesn't work - but **is there a way that this type of idea can be done?** The only thing I can think of would be something like this...

```
var names = ["Bob", "Jane"];

angular
  .constant("names", names)
  .constant("friends", getFriends())
  .controller("myController", MyController);

function getFriends() {
  var friends = {};

  names.forEach(function(name) {
    friends[name] = { firstName: name };
  });

  return friends;
}
```

...  but I'm trying to avoid this scenario (I'd like to have the constants defined in separate JS files).

**Note**: The reason I'm not using a factory for `friends` is because I want both of the constants available during the configuration phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is a firm **No** - you cannot pass a constant to a constant.

I ended up [using a provider instead](http://jsbin.com/caziciqado/1/edit?html,js,output):

```
angular
    .module("myApp", [])
    .constant("names", ["Bob", "Jane"])
    .provider("friends", FriendsProvider);

FriendsProvider.$inject = ["names"];

function FriendsProvider(names) {
    var self = this;
    self.friends = {};

    // ----- 8< -----  

    self.$get = [function() {
      return self.friends;  
    }];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do some processing in the `config` phase of the module, [where constants are available](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies):

```
angular.module('myModule').constant('names', ['Bob', 'Jane']);
angular.module('myModule').constant('friends', {});

angular.module('myModule').config(function(names, friends) {
  names.forEach(function(name) {
    // Modifying the friends constant
    friends[name] = { firstName: name };
  });
});
```

Note that while you can't change what object constant refers to, you can change the object itself.

Comment: Interesting approach... though it feels like it violates what is meant by a constant!